# Preparing To Make Website Internet Explorer 8 Compatible

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, jslint, quirks-mode

I have just taken over maintenance of a [large web application](http://hypernumbers.com/) which is over 10,000 lines of Javascript.

At the moment it runs on Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+ and Chrome and I have to make it work with IE8.

I am a very experienced programmer but I only have a little Javascript experience - although I have been introduced to the dubious pleasure of [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) and I have a copy of [Javascript The Good Parts.](http://astore.amazon.com/hypernumbersc-20/detail/0596517742)

The Javascript uses a lot of [JQuery](http://jquery.org) (and so great chunks of it are good to go).

I want to go about it in a systematic manner and would like advice on how to structure my porting activities.

The general methodology is the old 'OpenBSD generalise' strategy - when a cross-site bug is found systematically search the code base for other places where that might occur and fix them out.

BGerrison has just pointed out that I need to consider CSS compatibility as well, so lets chuck that in the mix too.

So far all I have come up with for a methodology is:

- run [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) and fix up any linting bugs

Are there any structured steps I should take or resources I should be familiar with before I plunge in?

***Update***

I discovered that the console in Opera 10 kinda lints your css and reports any css typos and stuff...

Comment: Crucial step for each bug: 'Is it really a JS bug or a CSS bug'. Especially where IE is concerned.

Comment: (Edited the question to reflect this comment) Erk! - so is there a CSS linter or any other automatic tools I should use? And what CSS resources should I be familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

- JSlint is good for checking syntax and maintaing code quality
- **BUT** browser differences are 99% **DOM** related
- Download and use: [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Script_Debugger)
- In case something is wrong, check [Bug Reports for Explorer Windows](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/explorer_windows/index.html)

**CSS**

- [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)
- [CSS Differences in Internet Explorer](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/)

Comment: Actually IE8 has the script debugger built-in.